# Are there any statements that can be used to run the code(s) again?

Tags: python, user-input

```
import random
import sys


print("Password Generator")    
print("* Attention: - You may not generate a password with more than 70 characters\n"
      "             - You may not enter letters")

characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" \
             "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*"
pass_length = input("Enter your password length: ")
```

Here I just want to make sure the information that the user's input are numbers, not letters!

```
if pass_length.isnumeric() is False:
    sys.exit("Natural numbers only!")
```

Is there a statement that can automatically run the script again after the "if" statement above is activated?

```
 def password_gen_start():
        password = "".join(random.sample(characters, int(pass_length)))
        print("Your password has been generated: " + format(password))


if int(pass_length) >= 71 and pass_length.isnumeric() is True:
    sys.exit("Password cannot be longer than 70 characters!")

if int(pass_length) < 71 and pass_length.isnumeric() is True:
    password_gen_start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put it in a while loop :

```
stop = ""
while stop != "yes":
    pass_length = input("Enter your password length: ")
    while not pass_length.isnumeric():
        pass_length = input("Natural numbers only !\n Enter your password length: ")
    # you put here the stuff that you want to execute
    stop=input("do you want to stop ?")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to ask one more thing, do you know how to repeat the code at the end of it?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: repeat the whole code ?

Comment: well yeah, i want this code to become like a generator that automatically run for users to input information in it

Comment: I edited my answer. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: thank you man, i'm new to Python so there's a lot of statements that I don't even know about (i started to learn this yesterday)

Comment: Good luck in your python learning journey !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nicolas, now I can finally finish my code:

```
import random

print("Password Generator")
print("* Attention: - You may not generate a password with more than 70 characters\n"
          "             - You may not enter letters")
characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" \
             "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*"
pass_length = input("Enter your password length: ")
while not pass_length.isnumeric() or int(pass_length) >= 71:
    pass_length = input("Natural numbers no larger than 70 only !\nEnter your password length: ")

def password_gen_start():
    password = "".join(random.sample(characters, int(pass_length)))
    print("Your password has been generated: " + format(password))

if int(pass_length) < 71 and pass_length.isnumeric() is True:
    password_gen_start()
```